# getting parse error on input '=' error (haskell)

Tags: haskell

my function append takes a list of lists [[a], [b,c], [d,e]] and returns a single list [a,b,c,d,e].
I wrote this in a file so i didn't have to use "let" but i still get parse error on input '='. can anyone help? 
thanks

```
append :: [[a]] -> [a]
append [[a]] = [ a | len = length a, n = 1, head a ++ (a !! n) , n < len]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `let` for `len` and `n`:

```
append [[a]] = [a | let len = length a, let n = 1, head a ++ (a !! n), n < len]
```

But this won't solve all of your problems, once the `let`s are added it doesn't typecheck, and `[[a]]` is probably not the pattern you want to use here.  The pattern `[[a]]` will only match a list like `[[1]]`, it won't match `[]`, or `[[1, 2]]`, or `[[1], [2]]`.

You also have another problem that `head a ++ (a !! n)` should be an expression that returns a `Bool`, but in this case it's returning a list.  Any "naked" expressions on the right side of the `|` in a list comprehension must evaluate to a `Bool` value.

If you're wanting to flatten a list of lists, I would suggest looking at the built-in [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#concat) function, which is actually defined using `foldr`.  Folds can be tricky to learn, though, so I'll show an alternate definition using explicit recursion:

```
myconcat :: [[a]] -> [a]
myconcat [] = []
myconcat (x:xs) = x ++ myconcat xs
```

This is equivalent to the `foldr` definition, but hopefully it can be more instructive to how to solve this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to use `let` to define local variables inside a list comprehension regardless of whether or not the code is in a file. The code being in a file only makes a difference for top-level definitions. Local definitions stay the same.

So the syntactically correct version of your code would be:

```
append :: [[a]] -> [a]
append [[a]] = [ a | let len = length a, let n = 1, head a ++ (a !! n) , n < len]
--                   ^^^                 ^^^
```